# How can i fix android studio emulator run problem?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

I have some trouble about android studio. if anybody know this program, please read description of my problem.
I created empty activity project android 5.0(lolipop) and just click run by emulator. I already tried different kind of devices, but the error is the same. My friends have no problem like that.
please tell me what to do.[screenshot of emulator error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhOU2.png) and  [photo of log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCHhu.png)
[updated event log after trying reinstall emulator devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPhrR.png)

Comment: Go to C drive > Users > yourname > .android > avd. There you will find all the downloaded emulators you have. Now delete all the files from there and download fresh emulator. If still same error comes update error log again. :)

Comment: I did that and get me same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Bandicam installed like it's suggesting? It's complaining about your Vulkan drivers ( you could update those) and Bandicam messing with them (you could uninstall that).

Alternatively you can open your AVD Manager, edit the AVD you're using, and set `Emulated Performance: Graphics` to `Software` (can't do it on every image for some reason - my API 29 Pixel 3 image won't let me change it, my API 30 Pixel 3XL image will). It'll run worse, but it'll run (well it should anyway)

Comment: Yeah, it was bandicam's fault.I had no idea. I just uninstall bandicam and my problem fixed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the flatpak of android studio on linux, run "flatpak update" and that should resolve your issues.

If you don't use the flatpak on linux, try restarting your machine and if that doesn't work, do a clean reinstall of your graphics driver.

Don't know why people keep trying to recommend software rendering, it's horrible and not at all practical, it's a barely working workaround not a solution.